# How can I scroll a Microsoft Word 2013 document up 1 pixel?

Tags: c#, word-automation

I've tried a few things.

Firstly:

```
GetScrollInfo(handle, (int)ScrollBarDirection.SB_VERT, ref si);

// Increase position by 1 pixels
si.nPos += 1;

// Reposition scroller
SetScrollInfo(handle, (int)ScrollBarDirection.SB_VERT, ref si, true);
```

However it doesn't work, I've tried all the window handles I can find with Spy associated with word and none of them budge.

I've tried using SendInput in conjunction with AutoScroll, but it just doesn't do it either (I suspect it is because I'm doing the mouse clicks and movements in rapid succession - but I don't want to delay them as it will interfere with people using word to type/etc, plus it feels wrong to do it that way.  Note I've tried both single and doubleclick combinations on the middle mouse button)
This is that code:

```
            INPUT mouseMoveInput = new INPUT();
            mouseMoveInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
            mouseMoveInput.mkhi.mi.dx = left;
            mouseMoveInput.mkhi.mi.dy = top;
            mouseMoveInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
            SendInput(1, ref mouseMoveInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));

            INPUT mouseDownInput = new INPUT();
            mouseDownInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
            mouseDownInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN;
            SendInput(1, ref mouseDownInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));

            INPUT mouseUpInput = new INPUT();
            mouseUpInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
            mouseUpInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP;
            SendInput(1, ref mouseUpInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));

            SendInput(1, ref mouseDownInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));
            SendInput(1, ref mouseUpInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT())); 


            mouseMoveInput.mkhi.mi.dx = 0;
            mouseMoveInput.mkhi.mi.dy = 150;
            mouseMoveInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
            SendInput(1, ref mouseMoveInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));

            SendInput(1, ref mouseDownInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));
            SendInput(1, ref mouseUpInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));
```

The smallscroll and autoscroll that come with the word application com object are either a whole line jump or leave the mouse in a state that any movement swings the document everywhere.

I want single pixel scrolling at a time as it looks much smoother, but want to control it programmatically without interfering with the user